# iOS Credit Card Processing SDK with Signature View

Tags: ios, paypal, stripe-payments, credit-card, square

I'm trying to do credit card processing in my app. Basically it's a self developed POS and needs to process credit card. Is there an SDK out there that does something like Square, where a customer scan a credit card, then the SDK brings up a Signature View for the customer to sign then confirmed. Does PayPal or Stripe, or any of the SDK out there do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

PayPal has its own project for scanning Credit Cards called [card.io](https://www.card.io/)

It's in Open Source now, so you can find more at their [GitHub page](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK).

There is also a Sample App there, very useful.

But this must be considered as half an answer since there are no Signature over the screen possibilities there.

Comment: Thanks. I did notice PayPal purchased card.io and now it's part of their SDK. I'm familiar with PayPal, but didn't really see anything on the signature, was hoping someone know something about it or an alternative solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The PayPal product you are likely looking for is [PayPal Here](https://www.paypal.com/here). There are a number of options that provide POS functionality, though IDK about a signature view.

The regular SDK is NOT designed for POS use. card.io is just a fancy card number input device. It doesn't do any payment processing.